# Pytorch error loading state dict of model: Expected state_dict to be dict-like

Tags: python, pytorch, state-dict

I am trying to save and load a model, but there is always an error.
I save the model with:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(),'01.Code/models/SNNNotEncoded.pth' )
```

and I try to load the model with

```
model.load_state_dict('01.Code/models/SNNNotEncoded.pth')
```

Then, the following error will come up:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/demaisch/git/ros_workspaces/demaisch_ws/PythonFIles/SNNtrainNotEncoded.py",
> line 26, in 
> model.load_state_dict('01.Code/models/SNNNotEncoded.pth')
> File
> "/home/demaisch/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
> line 1994, in load_state_dict
> raise TypeError("Expected state_dict to be dict-like, got {}.".format(type(state_dict))) TypeError: Expected state_dict to be
> dict-like, got <class 'str'>

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`model.load_state_dict` does not take a filepath but a dictionnary giving the weights of all layers (see [this link from pytorch doc](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-load-state-dict-recommended)). To use the saved state dict, you must load it before.

You can replace your second line with :

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('01.Code/models/SNNNotEncoded.pth'))
```

`torch.load` first loads the object saved in the file, and it is then given to the `load_state_dict` function which sets all the weights of your model.

Answer (score 3):

first load the state_dict from the file then create a new instance of your model and finally load the state_dict into the model:

```
state_dict = torch.load('01.Code/models/SNNNotEncoded.pth')
model = YourModelClass()

model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
```